# PHP Include : Error 500 when migrating web application from Windows to Linux

Tags: php

PHP info server Windows :

Windows NT TEXTER 6.1 build 7600 (Windows 7 Business Edition) AMD64

Server API Apache 2.0 Handler

PHP Version 5.4.12

---

PHP info server Linux :

Linux 2.6.18-028stab094.3 #1 SMP Thu Sep 22 12:47:37 MSD 2011 x86_64

Server API CGI/FastCGI

PHP Version 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.22

---

Work in Windows but don't work in Linux (Error 500):

```
<?php include "$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/module/require/file.php "; ?>
```

I have change with this code and work in both system :

```
<?php @include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/module/require/file.php" ); ?>
```

The error 500 is generated because there is a different version of PHP ?

Comment: Linux is case sensitive. Be sure the filename matches!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using arrays in String literals can cause problems. Your line `"$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/module/require/file.php"` can result in a string like

```
"(array)[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/module/require/file.php"
```

Enclose subscripted arrays in braces, like this:

```
"{$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]}/module/require/file.php"
```

It seems like the different versions of php handle such cases differently.

Alternatively, you can simply concatenate the strings, as you did in your working solution.

Comment: I try your suggestion with the arrays in braces but still have the same eror 500 in Linux. Only my solution working.

Comment: I just saw that you have an extra blank space character in your orginal post. Maybe this causes the problem?